# преобразовать один date() в другой

Tags: php

Есть ли такая функция которая преобразит `date()` в дату на 7 дней вперед?

К примеру, сегодня 08.11.2015. Как её преобразовать в 15.11.2015?

Comment: ну в Google посмотреть можно же? простой же вопрос... PHP программирование. третий день....

Answer (score 1):

Например через `ООП` и класс [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.datetime.php):

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->modify('+7 days')->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов много

```
$date = date_create();
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('7 days'));
echo date_format($date, 'd.m.Y');
```

Ну или вот такой вариант:

```
echo date('d.m.Y', mktime(0,0,0,date('m'), date('d')+7, date('Y'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть много варантов, например:

**1.**

```
$date = new DateTime();    
$date->modify('+7 day');

//или
$diff24Hours = new DateInterval('PT24H');    
$date->add($diff24Hours);
```

(при этом `$date` - объект типа `DateTime`)

**2.**

```
$timestamp = round(microtime(true)*1000); //Количество секунд, прошедших с полуночи 1 января 1970 года.
$timestamp_new = $timestamp + 3600*24*7; // 3600*24*7 - количество секунд в неделе.
```

Comment: Ваш способ рабочий, но без пояснений автор его не осилит. Очевидно он пока не слышал о типах.

Answer (score 0):

Если коротко:

```
$date += 7 * (24 * 60 * 60); // в сутках 24 часа по 60 минут по 60 секунд
```

Подробнее: **всегда имейте в виду тип данных!** Функция [date()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) возвращает строку, а не дату. А для вычислений вам нужна настоящая дата (дата-время), а не строка. В PHP есть два типа дат:

- Unix timestamp, это число секунд с полуночи по Гринвичу 1 января 1970г. Такое значение возвращает time(), mktime(), filemtime() идругие, а также неявно использует на входе date().
  `$time+1` означает "через одну секунду после времени $time", а `$time+604800` соответственно "через семь суток после времени $time".
  Функция date() всего-лишь преобразует эти секунды в читабельную строку.
- Класс [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php). Представление времени в виде объекта со своими методами.

Примеры для обоих типов:
Unix timestamp

```
$date = time() + 604800; // или $date = strtotime('+7 days');
echo date('d.m.Y', $date);
```

DateTime

```
$date = date_create();
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('7 days'));
echo date_format($date, 'd.m.Y');
```